# Change the functionality of text field on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a text field for entering the address in a form and also a link with the text containing set custom address.If the user starts entering address,the addresses stored in the database will be displayed below by the help of ajax.My issue is that when the user clicks the link present in the right side of the text box(that is set custom address),i do not want to display the event for ajax.I need to know,if the id of the textbox can be changed on click of the link,or is it possible to generate another text box above the older text box.
My code is like this:

```
function set_custom_address()
{
    var custom_venue_link = document.getElementById('custom_venue_link');
    if(custom_venue_link.innerHTML=="custom address")
    {
        document.getElementById('venue').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('venue_new').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('custom').value= "true";
        custom_venue_link.innerHTML = "tag venue";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('venue_new').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('venue').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('custom').value= "false";
        custom_venue_link.innerHTML = "custom address";
    }
}
```

My html code is like this:

```
<input id="venue" name="venue" type="text"  
placeholder="Tag venue name" onkeyup="showData(this.value)" />
<input id="venue_new" name="venue_new" type="text" 
placeholder="Tag venue_name" style="display:none;"/> &nbsp; or 
<a   id="custom_venue_link" href="" 
onclick="set_custom_address();return false;">custom address</a></li>
```

Comment: Yes, both are possible. You can change the ID of an element with `element.id = "newid";`. You can add another textbox by manipulating the DOM. You haven't really provided enough information for someone to post an answer with code, I think.

Comment: @Barmar if the user clicks on the link,it means the user is creating a new address which is not there in the database.

Comment: OK, but what does changing the textbox element's ID have to do with that?

Comment: You could also remove the `keyup` event handler from `venue`

Comment: I have a method called showData() in the text field.I would like to have only one text field.if the user doesnt click on the link,the code inside the showData() needs to work.If he does click the link,the method should not fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of addind another input or changin its id, you could attach and dettach the event handler by code.

When the page load you should attach the event:

```
document.getElementById("venue").onkeyup = function(){showData(this.value);};
```

Then on set_custom_address you can dettach it:

```
document.getElementById("venue").onkeyup = null;
```

<strike>And attach it again at the end in case the user start editing the value on input again (or you could just make it readonly).</strike> I see you are hidding it.

---

*Edit*: the following is the code to make it readonly, just in case:

```
document.getElementById("venue").setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
```

And you can remove it like this:

```
document.getElementById("venue").removeAttribute("readonly");
```

Note 1: I don't know if was anything causing onkeyup to fire, still if the field is readonly it will not generate that event from user input.

Note 2: It was mentioned that the addresses from the database were shown under the field, I don't know if extra steps are needed to hide that. Maybe a function "hideData()" will be necessary.

Comment: If i write document.getElementById("venue").onkeyup = null; inside the set_custom_address(),it wil work??